# Optimal code generation for evaluation of a fixed set of multivariate rational polynomials

Tags: polynomials, compile, algorithm, code-generation

Given a set of multivariate rational polynomials, is it possible to find the optimal (shortest or least expensive in some other sense) sequence of arithmetical operations, such that it results in evaluation of said polynomials? I understand that finding the optimal solution might be a yet unsolved NP-hard problem. However, I will happily accept approximate solutions as well.

As a practical example, this piece of code produces a set of 9 polynomials in 4 variables:

```
(* Just an illustration. My question is not about these particular polynomials. *)
ker[x_] := {1/4 (1 - 2 x), 1/2, 1/4 (1 + 2 x)}
polys = 
  Flatten@Integrate[
    Outer[Times, ker[x], ker[y]] /. {y -> a x + b}, {x, x0, x1}]
```

Currently, my ad-hoc approach is to tweak the expression with various functions such as `FullSimplify`, and compile it to see what works better:

```
Compile[{{a,_Real},{b,_Real},{x0,_Real},{x1,_Real}}, Evaluate@Expand@polys]
```

Judging by the length of `CompilePrint` (53 lines), this is the best generated code I've managed to come up with. Is it possible to do even better? Is there an algorithm sophisticated enough to reinvent Strassen's matrix multiplication formula? Or is there something in between?

I'm hoping for a Mathematica package, but will gladly accept links to other software capable of solving problems such as described. Referring to relevant research papers would also be very helpful.

Comment: Try `HornerForm`. That's normally pretty good at reducing the multiplications.

Comment: `Compile[{{y, _Real}, {a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x0, _Real}, {x1, _Real}}, Evaluate@N@Simplify@polys]` requires only 51 lines. But the number of lines is an unreliable measurement of complexity...

Comment: If compiling to C code, you could also get the `CForm` of your polynomials and put them into CompilerExplorer to look at how many instructions it generates and if the expression is adequately vectorized. For example this shows that under -O3 optimizations and with AVX2 support enabled the `HornerForm` expression of `polys[[1]]` actually compiles down to more instructions to my surprise, and it may be slower https://godbolt.org/z/wEjQM9 though you would need to profile it to determine this.

Comment: Also for polynomials in a matrix variable see this from Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method: _Horner's method is optimal, in the sense that any algorithm to evaluate an arbitrary polynomial must use at least as many operations. Alexander Ostrowski proved in 1954 that the number of additions required is minimal.[3] Victor Pan proved in 1966 that the number of multiplications is minimal.[4] However, when x is a matrix, Horner's method is not optimal. [citation needed]_ .  And perhaps take a look at this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379517306389

Comment: @Flinty, Henrik Schumacher, thank you. Your suggestions are new to me and will definitely be useful in other areas. But here I was hoping that some sophisticated algorithm had been developed specifically for rational polynomials, capable of going far beyond the univariate Horner form and common compiler heuristics. Flinty's latest link seems very promising. I'll think of purchasing it or searching further on (keywords are invaluable!)

Comment: @aooiiii ^  I found some Patterson-Stockmeyer algorithm code for matrix polynomials in maple here: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs487/handouts/patstock.mpl - it's probably a runner up to the state-of-the-art in that paper. There's also a way to do it with the FFT and division but I doubt that helps much for small polynomials https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800152.804900

Comment: @flinty, wow, actual working code! Just before I start digging into the new topic + new language, are you sure this algorithm can be adapted to the many-variable case?

Comment: Sorry if my wording could have been interpreted as sarcasm. Indeed, it could have (since, formally, I didn't get exactly what I asked for), but honestly, I was simply expressing excitement from all the new information and an opportunity to learn Maple, hence the "wow". Funny that it probably still sounds like sarcasm, but it's not my fault I'm not a native English speaker.